# Meaning of arr +1, *arr+1 , **arr+1 in 3D array

Tags: c, arrays

I have this question:
say starting address is 100.

```
int arr[2][3][2] = {{{2,4},{7,8},{3,4}},{{2,2},{2,3},{3,4}}};
printf(“%u %u %u %d \n”,arr,*arr,**arr,***arr); // Line 2
printf(“%u %u %u %d \n”,arr+1,*arr+1,**arr+1,***arr+1); // Line 3
}
Answer:
100, 100, 100, 2
114, 104, 102, 3
```

**Explanation:**

For Line 3: `arr+1` increases in the third dimension thus points to value
at 114, `*a+1` increments in second dimension thus points to 104, `**arr +1`
increments the first dimension thus points to 102 and `***arr+1` first gets the
value at first location and then increments it by 1. Hence is the output of second line.

[image: Memory Layout]

My Question - I tried my best. but i could get what explanation meant for Line 3 ! please explain

Comment: `***arr` My eyes and brain get hurt when I see it.

Comment: Because of precedence, `*arr + 1` is the value stored at `arr` added to the number 1.

Comment: @Kevin In this example the value stored at `arr` has type `int [3][2]`. You can not add it to the number 1

Comment: @kotlomoy `arr` decays into a pointer, so it adds 1 via pointer arithmetic; it actually increases the value by something > 1, but it is valid to `+1` a pointer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What is type of `int arr[2][3][2]`? It is array of 2 elements of type `int [3][2]`. This is 3rd dimension.

What is `int [3][2]`? It is array of 3 elements of type `int [2]`. This is 2nd dimension.

What is `int [2]`? It is array of 2 elements of type `int`. This is 1st dimension.

Here's diagram

[image]

In line 2:

- `arr` points to first element of 3rd dimension,
- `*arr` points to first element of 2nd dimension,
- `**arr` points to first element of 1st dimension,
- `***arr` takes the value of first element of 1st dimension.

You can see from diagram that all dimensions start from address `100`. Hence the output of line 2: "100, 100, 100, 2".

In line 3:

- `arr + 1` points to second element of 3rd dimension,
- `*arr + 1` points to second element of 2nd dimension,
- `**arr + 1` points to second element of 1st dimension,
- `***arr + 1` takes the value of first element of 1st dimension and increments it.

You can see from diagram that second element of 3rd dimension has address `112` (not 114!), second element of 2nd dimension has address `104`, second element of 1st dimension has address `102`. Hence the output of line 3 must be: "112, 104, 102, 3"

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is wrong.  The first value for line 3 should be 112, not 114.

When you use arithmetic on a pointer, it changes the address by some number of elements (of whatever size the array stores).  When you use an array as if it were a pointer, C will manage that for you.

When you use `arr`, the compiler will say you have a pointer to an array holding two elements of type `int[3][2]`.  So adding one to that means adding `sizeof(int[3][2])` which is 12.  Here is a table to show this:

```
code      element type   ints per element    bytes per element   array length
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
arr       int[3][2]      6                   12                  2
*arr      int[2]         2                   4                   3
**arr     int            1                   2                   2
```

Comment: great explanation with the help of table

Answer (score 0):

there isn't much value in any "explanation" within your example. See, you're mixing things up. That's because your multi-*-ing (***arr and the like) only is sensible, if you're allocating with C's malloc. Then the rows of a 2D array are arr[i] of type (int *), and within any row a column value is arr[i][j] of type (int), and the whole 2D matrix is **arr of type (int **). In 3D you have arr[i][j][k] of type (int) down to ***arr for the whole 3D structure. But using int arr[2][3][2] = {...}, just use arr[i][j][k] to get a matrix element and i.e. arr[0], arr[1] for the rows. Pointers aren't really useful with those compile-time allocated 2-3D matrices. Always remember ***arr is a pointer to a pointer to a pointer, if and only if someone came along and did all the C-malloc-ing. Regards, M.

Comment: Sorry, the system did eat up all my asteriks, so don'r read that. M.